# How to I prevent Visual Studio from showing application insights reminder?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, ide, azure-application-insights

Occasionally, while working in visual studio 2015 IDE, I received window reminding me that I can use Application insights. However, I dont see any disable button on the window itself and would like to disable the notifications. How can I ensure that I no longer receive these notifications?

Comment: it should never be a modal dialog which prevents you from doing anything, though.  is it just a popup notification that goes away on its own?

Answer (score 5):

I found it out. Looks like Microsoft wanted to make it a little tricky to disable the notifications. ;) I had to do the following ;

1. Search for application insights in toolbar

[image: Search for insights toolbar]

2. Click "enable application insight notifications" to disable. That ensures it wont show again.

[image: Click to disable]

Comment: not "tricky", but not many other good places to put it.  we could do a whole settings page, but it would have just that one checkbox, and it wouldn't really be any easier to find.

Comment: Hi @JohnGardner, Thank you for the response. I don't think an entire settings page is necessary. Instead, the initial window that shows should have a button that says "Dont Ask Me Again". This is very common for applications that show reminders. Example: Chrome browser asks "make this my default browser" with option to disable to notification AT THE MOMENT WHEN THE NOTIFICATION IS SHOWN. This is optimal since its right when the end user is asked about the option.

Comment: the close button in the notification itself is that button, but specific to that "type" of notification.  otherwise we need to have 2 different "never show me this" and "never show me anything" buttons/links and people get confused.

Comment: its not that complicated John. Perhaps I am not doing a good enough job communicating. What I am proposing is having a simple button on the window that is showing now, and that simple button doing EXACTLY what it says "dont show me again". I cant see this being that complex, nor can I see this relating to disabling any other notification other than the one that is shown.

Comment: like i said, if you want "don't show me this again", that button already exists in the notification window, that's what the X close button does in our notifications.  If you want a "and don't show me anything else either" we have that as well in our toolbar, as you've already found.

Comment: Hi John, I definitely am confused. Nevertheless, I appreciate your contribution. Thank you for the help.

Comment: The dialog actually truly has a link that says "Don't show this again" however, clicking that does not do what it promises. Thanks for this guide!